# Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Distinct'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am having trouble with this error message as the line it errors on is not actually using Distinct() at all. I am wondering if it is something to do with the `IEqualityComparer` I've implemented?

It creates an unsupported exception in a view on this line, specifically on `.Count()`:

```
tr style="display: @( Model.FeaturedOffers.Count() == 0 ? "" : "none" ) " id="none">
```

Here is the IEqualityComparer class:

```
public class RewardOfferEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<OfferOverviewViewModel>
{
    public bool Equals(OfferOverviewViewModel x, OfferOverviewViewModel y)
    {
        return Equals(x.OfferId, y.OfferId);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(OfferOverviewViewModel x)
    {
        return x.OfferId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found that calling `.ToList().Distinct()` instead of `.Distinct()` solved the problem.

Found answer [here](http://dkowalski.com/blog/archive/2009/11/27/unsupported-overload-used-for-query-operator-distinct.aspx)

Comment: Note that if that is a table you are forcing all those records out of the database and into memory - you might be better off writing an SP to return all the unique offers.

Answer (score 3):

You might not be using `Distinct()`, but somehere in the chain of enumerables represented by `Model.FeaturedOffers` I'm guessing there's an `IQueryable` expression that's using a `Distinct` call that is not supported by the underlying provider - for example Linq to SQL or Entity Framework.

For example - if you are querying a Table in Entity Framework and passing your own comparer then that most certainly won't work - since there's no way for EF to re-implement the comparer in SQL or eSQL

Comment: could you just help the person instead and provide an solution?